# Pass arguments for use in a grandchild process

Tags: bash, shell-script, environment-variables, variable, arguments

I have a list of arguments and three processes:

```
bash_script -> child -> grandchild
```

The list of arguments is aimed at the grandchild. I can modify all three processes. The grandfather script gets one argument for itself.

Is the following a proper way to pass the remaining arguments to the grandchild?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# This is the grandfather    
first_arg="$1"
shift 1;

export MY_ARGS="$@"
```

I "spread" the env variable later, in the child process, as part of the command that calls the grandchild, something like:

```
grandchild --foo "$MY_ARGS"  # append $MY_ARGS as arguments to foo
```

Comment: I think this question is unclear. What are you trying to achieve? What's the input? What are your limitations? Why do you want to use env vars?

Comment: I am simply trying to store arguments so I can apply them later in a grandchild process

Comment: Are you able to modify the grandchild process? Is there any requirement how the arguments should arrive there?

Comment: I have control of the grandchild process, so any solution will do, doesn't have to be an env variable perse

Comment: And are you in control (able to edit) the intermediate process?

Comment: Yep I control intermediate process too

Comment: If you control all the scripts/programs, then I don't see any issue with passing tho command line arguments as command line arguments between the stages of your processing.

Comment: @Kusalananda yes, but let's say it's a great grandchild, kinda of annoying to pass it 3 times. env variable would be more convenient, as long you give it a unique name, and it will be all good.

Comment: So there's a great grandchild as well?...

Comment: No in this case, it's a grandchild, but if it were a great-grandchild, I wouldn't want to pass the arguments along 3 times, using an env var would be more convenient.

Comment: If you're are starting process trees that are four or five or more levels deep, and you need to pass the initial command line arguments down to a leaf process, then you may want to start thinking about the organization of your project.

Comment: @Kusalananda yes that's true, I am using Docker here though, and that's why there are some serious layers.  I created a new question that distills this problem down a bit - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/450714/map-array-of-arguments-and-then-convert-to-string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a script, you should not demote an array to a string.  An environment variable and its value is a simple `key=value` pair where both `key` and `value` are strings.  Demoting the positional parameters to a simple string (by concatenation) will make it difficult to retain separation between them, and it would be hard to get quoting right when you end up wanting to use them.

Instead, pass the positional parameters (command line argument) that you want to pass to the next script on its command line.

```
#!/bin/bash

first_arg=$1
shift

# later ...

./my_other_script "$@"
```

In the other script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# use "$@" here
foo --bar "$@"
```

Comment: I need to store it in an env var, because foo is a subprocess launched from another subprocess.

Comment: do you think @mOdular's answer is ok?

Comment: An environment variable is a simple `key=value` pair.  If you demote the array to a simple string, then you lose the ability to distinguish between the original arguments, unless you explicitly delimit them in a way that you carefully arrange (and then parse that string).  The best way is to never demote the elements to the bits of the same string and instead pass them on the command line as separate arguments.  Exporting arrays may possible be working in `bash` (I honestly don't know), but it seems like a hack if anything.

Comment: As it stands, tbh this doesn't answer the question. I updated the OP to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: it seems you can't export arrays in bash.  You might need to export a function that sets up the array or something similar.

You should use an array, otherwise arguments with spaces will expand to multiple words.

```
export MY_ARGS=("$@")


foo --bar "${MY_ARGS[@]}"
```

Comment: thanks, probably more along the lines of what I am thinking

Comment: hmmm, why not `export MY_ARGS="${MY_ARGS[@]}"`?

Comment: Actually, I don't think this will work.  See my edit.  There are other questions on this site about this.

Comment: I think what I just suggested will work, above your last comment

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why people are confused by the question, but maybe the question is confusing, here is what seems to work fine for me:

```
my_args_array=("$@")
export MY_ARGS="${my_args_array[@]}"
```

then we simply use `MY_ARGS` like so:

```
foo --bar $MY_ARGS
```

**note** as @Kusalananda points out: this will *fail* if the original arguments have whitespace in them. And in that case, it's best to pass arguments through child processes using `$@`, instead of an env variable.

Comment: Arrays don't export in Bash. (Or if they do, then not this way.) I think you're mixing together two different things, which makes you think you're right.

Comment: Try that with `set -- 'hello world' '1 2 3' 'abc'`. You can't any longer distinguish between these three positional parameters in `$MY_ARGS`.

Comment: hmmm I agree that there might be a problem, but I don't exactly follow, what is the set command?

Comment: The `set` command sets the positional parameters, `$1`, `$2` etc.  These are available as the array `$@`.

Comment: @Kusalananda ok I think I see what you are saying, so to fix this, could you do something like:  `export MY_ARGS="${my_args_array[@].join("'")}"`, that is, join surround argument in the array with single quotes? join is not the right function, but some sort of map.

Comment: You could join them with a delimiter, yes. As in `( IFS="'"; echo "$*" )`, but then you have the issue of what happens when one of the arguments contains a delimiter character, and you would have to parse the resulting string before using it.

Comment: @Kusalananda yes that might work, here is a new question that related to the problem you described here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/450714/map-array-of-arguments-and-then-convert-to-string

Answer (score 2):

The general answer is this. You can pass the args using:

- command line positional parameters
- environment variables
- any IPC (Inter-Process Communication) available on your OS

To focus on just the first two,

- Positional parameters are the most natural way. This involves possible edition and further transmission of `"$@"`, which stands for all currently defined positional parameters. This has to be done on all stages of the process hierarchy.
- The environment variables are not as straight-forward as the positional parameters, as they come in a form of key-and-value pair. Even if you pass values this way, you need the keys to get them. As long as they're not the only environment variables, which I wouldn't assume without adequate consideration. But this method is viable. All you need to do is to share the keys among the interested parties. The keys themselves can be based on a pattern. Here's an example of how this can be done.

  There are two scripts -- `p.bash` and `c.bash`. `p` stands for a parent, while `c` is the child. They can be separated by intermediaries, as long as those don't remove the values transmitted through the environment.
  For simplicity, these two scripts have an immediate connection in that `p.bash` calls `c.bash`.

  Here's `p.bash`:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  shift #consume the first argument
  #parse and export the other arguments
  prefix=abcdef_
  i=0
  for a in "$@"; do
      export "$prefix""$i"="$a"
      ((i++))
  done
  ./c.bash
  ```

  And here's `c.bash`:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  #consume the env arguments
  prefix=abcdef_
  env | grep ^"$prefix"
  ```

  And here's the execution:

  ```
  $ ./p.bash arg "1 2" "3 4" "5 6"
  abcdef_0=1 2
  abcdef_1=3 4
  abcdef_2=5 6
  ```

  I'll explain two lines, one from each script.

  The first one is the generator,

  ```
   export "$prefix""$i"="$a"
  ```

  `export` populates the environment with variables of form `abcdef_0`, `abcdef_1`, etc. Now the child processes can find them in their environments. (As long as they're not unset by some intermediary.)

  `env | grep ^"$prefix"` in the child is the consumer. `env` lists the environment variables, and `grep` filters out all the lines not associated with the prefix responsible for the transmission in question. Once you understand what's going on here, you should be able to access the transmitted variables and make use of them inside the descendant process.

Comment: @ilkkachu Correct. I'll update my answer.