# map array of arguments and then convert to string

Tags: bash, shell-script, variable, arguments

Say I have these **bash** functions in a script:

```
foo(){
  my_args_array=("$@")
  export my_args="${my_args_array[@]}"
  bar $my_args
}

bar(){
  echo "number of args: $#";
}


foo a b 'c d e'
```

if I run the above script, I will get:

> number of args: 5

but what I am looking for is:

> number of args: 3

so my question is - is there a way to map the value returned by `my_args_array[@]`, so I can surround each element with single quotes? Or do whatever I need to do to make the env variable string look like the original command line arguments.

Comment: What do you want to do in the end? You say you want to turn the array into a string, but in the code you're passing it as an argument to a function, and talk about the number of args the function gets. So, do you really want the string, or do you want the array elements passed to a command as distinct arguments? If you have a more concrete use-case to present, it might help in suggesting an appropriate solution.

Comment: I want the argument `c d e` to remain as a single arg, not 3 args.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an array, not a string:

```
#!/bin/bash
foo(){
  my_args=("$@")
  bar "${my_args[@]}"
}

bar(){
  echo "number of args: $#";
}


foo a b 'c d e'
```

Comment: Does Bash export arrays?

Comment: @Tomasz, no, it doesn't.

Comment: This looks like it works great, thanks. @Kusalananda can you mention if this solves the original problem to a better extent? If someone could save my ass by supporting OP, I think this is a legit question.

Comment: @AlexanderMills This solves the original problem in [your other question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/450696/store-and-pass-arguments-for-use-in-a-grandchild-process) in exactly the same way as I showed in my answer there: By passing the array's values on the command line. The only difference is that choroba is using an array to hold the values of `$@` and then passes the quoted values.  He could have done `bar "$@"` directly.

Answer (score 3):

In Bash, using `"${array[@]}"` (or `"$@"`) in the right hand side of an assignment works a bit like `${array[*]}` (or `"$*"`): it joins the array elements to a single string, using spaces as separators. (`${array[*]}` (`"$*"`) uses the first character (byte?) of `IFS`.) This also applies to arguments of `export`, `declare`, `local` etc.

Then you have `a b c d e` in `my_args`, and the unquoted expansion splits.

If you want an array, use an array:

```
foo() {
    bar "$@"
}
bar() {
    echo "number of args: $#";
}
foo a b 'c d e'
```

Or, if you want a string, it's probably better to explicitly use `"${array[*]}"` for clarity.

(FWIW, Bash doesn't support exporting arrays through the environment [[1]](https://www.mail-archive.com/bug-bash@gnu.org/msg01774.html) [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564418/exporting-an-array-in-bash-script))

Comment: Sorry, my eyes skipped past the  "in an assignment" bit. You are correct.

Comment: @Kusalananda, but you're right, it's not really documented what happens. I posted a bug report on it a while ago, maybe it'll show up eventually. (Sadly, I don't think the online manual has been updated in a while.)